# black border around screen ati radeon hd 4550 graphic card on hdmi on windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, amd-radeon

I have bought a LG monitor 22 inch when I connect my PC buy HDMI cable to it there is a black border around the screen like this :

[image]

my graphic card model is **ATI hd 4550** .I have with her searched  for this problem and I found there were same problem for other peoples and in the solution I installed **AMD Catalyst Control Center** (in some of theme there was this name : **ATI Catalyst Control Center**) But In their solution this software is like this : 
[image]
But when I run  AMD Catalyst Control Center in my pc scaling options is missing like this :

[image]

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like the latest version of the ATI Catalyst Control Center to me. The issue you're facing does look like a scanning problem (meaning that your ATI Radeon HD4550 isn't interpreting your display's resolution properly), so you're on the right track. Take it a step further and reinstall the drivers for both the ATI Radeon HD4550 and the display; it's possible CCC isn't seeing that card/display because you have incorrect/outdated/missing drivers (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download). Make sure you get both directly from the manufacturers so you get the latest and greatest.

Comment: plz check this  : http://superuser.com/questions/900645/black-border-amd-catalyst-control-center-scaling-option-setting-resets-after-reb