# Black border AMD Catalyst Control Center scaling option setting resets after reboot/sleep /log of ...windows

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, sleep, amd-radeon

I have connected my **22 inch full hd** moniter to my pc by **HDMI** cable .
my graphic card is : **ATI radeon hd 4550** . there is black border around of my screen like this :

[image]

So I run **AMD Catalyst Control Center** and like below picture I seted **scaling options**  to 0 and problem solved !

[image]

BUT when I **reboot** or **sleep** or **shut dwon** windows , the **scaling options** returns to it's previous value and the black border coms back and I should set it again ! 
how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it ! I had to  select **restor Factory defaults** in **AMD Catalyst Control Center** and after that fix scaling options and reboot windows 
[image]